# button jquery ui not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use the button from the jQuery UI. for some reason, my button does not work properly. To test it out, I tried making the button to be disabled but when I run the program, it is still clickable. My script path files are right because I was using the slider jquery ui widget and it worked.

This is my code for my the script of my button:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#dateButton").button({
disabled:true
}); 

});
});
</script>
```

This is my button delcaration:

```
<button id="dateButton"> Date </button>
```

And these are the scripts I am using (using bootstrap):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

ALSO, if I were to call a function when the button is clicked, would I write it like this?:

```
$("#dateButton").button({
Code goes in here for the function
});
```

Comment: Is that script tag loaded before the button or after it?

Comment: Its loaded before the button

Comment: Regarding pt 2, to call a function when the button is clicked, add an event listener: `$("#dateButton").button().click(function(){ ... onclick code goes here  });`

Comment: That script with the jQuery in it should be right before the closing body tag.

Comment: Well if it is before, it is like trying to eat a pizza before you make it. Not going to happen. You can not reference an element before it exists. Use document ready.

Comment: did you download jqueryUI?

Comment: @FlipFloop yes I did.

Comment: @epascarello I have loaded all the libraries in my <head> tag

Comment: Dev Tools console output after clicking button?

Comment: @JoshKG There is one error: GET https://nikkomsgchannel/e?006b0050002d002700310030006c0054002e0053005b00570…54002f002d00300065005500580034005f0008005e002d005d0029002b002a002a005f005b

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6094

Comment: @epascarello oh i see now. Im guessing there no way of circumventing this problem no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bootstrap and jQuery UI do not get along with button see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6094

Solution is to use noConflict

```js
(function() {
  var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict();
  $.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton;
}());

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dateButton").button({
    disabled: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />

<button id="dateButton"> Date </button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m5ergv2a/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I pasted the function about the bootstrapButton into my code and it works. So is it possible for me to use all the jquery ui widgets that may interfere with bootstrap by using this method?

Comment: I think they this is the only one that has a naming conflict. Both declare $.fn.button...

Answer (score 0):

Even though your declaration is current for initializing a jquery UI button, you need to associate it during the page load which can be done during document.ready function.

```
$().ready(function()
    {

$("#dateButton").button({
}); 

$("#dateButton").click(function(){
 // do stuff here
 alert();
});
});
```

Example  : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/xBB5x/10222/

Also, make sure to get the reference to jquery-ui.css from CDN to confirm that the api is loaded correctly .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Its working in your jsfiddle but its not working on my code for some reason. Should I paste my whole code?